# Parse JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse the following json line in jquery:

```
[{
   "pk": 19,
   "model": "films.movies",
   "fields": {
       "length": "92",
       "name": "Beetle Juice",
       "actor": "Keaton", 
       "img_set": [{
             "pk": 42,
             "model": "films.img",
             "fields": {
                 "uploaded": "2010-10-08 21:44:30",
                 "f_movie": 19,
                 "url_med": "http://www.mondial-infos.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Beetlejuice.jpg"}
             }]
       }
},{
   "pk": 20,
   "model": "films.movies",
   "fields": {
      "length": "126",
      "name": "Batman",
      "actor": "Keaton", 
      "img_set": [{
            "pk": 43, 
            "model": "films.img",
            "fields": {
                  "uploaded": "2010-10-08 21:44:54",
                  "f_movie": 20, 
                  "url_med": "http://bruehoyt.com/superheroes/DC/batman/bruce/batmankeaton3.jpg"}
            }]
      }
}]
```

I can't access anything after img_set though.  What am I missing?  Is this valid json?

I am attempting the following:

```
$.getJSON('/films/feeds/movie-by-actor/Keaton/',function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, movie) {

        alert(movie.fields.name);
        alert(movie.fields.img_set[0].pk);

    });
});
```

The first alert works.  The second does not.

In addition, though I don't know that it matters, this is jquery within a django template.

Comment: are you getting an error? how you are accessing?

Comment: It's valid JSON. Do you mean you can't access any of the properties in the objects in the `img_set` array, or you can't access the second element in the main array? Code that demonstrates the problem you're having would help.

Comment: edited above with code I'm using to try to access data

Comment: you need  alert(movie[0].fields.img_set[0].pk); because move is an array look at Nick's code see how he has it in his

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing part is probably the array of a single element, but `img_set` is still an array.  Make sure you're accessing it with an index first, like this:

```
.img_set[0].pk
//for example:
data[0].fields.img_set[0].pk
```

Instead of just:

```
.img_set.pk
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ANvpD/).

Comment: First, thanks for the link.  That's a handy tool.  It's weird though that it works there, but it's not working in my code.  Same methodology. . .