# Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse this test.json (It does validates, so that doesn't appear to be an issue, it's in the same folder as the file containing the javascript below)

```
{
"mainunit": {
    "sensors": [
        {
            "id": "C9",
            "name": "Sensor 2",
            "tc": 71.3,
            "pair": null
        },
        {
            "id": "4A",
            "name": "Sensor 1",
            "tc": 106.7,
            "pair": null
        }
    ],
    "fans": null
}}
```

I'm trying to use this . . .

```
$.getJSON('test.json',function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, learning) {

    alert(learning.mainunit.sensors[0].tc);

});});
```

This code is from a previous SO question, see link below.

I also have a general questions about this previous question regarding parsing json with jQuery.

[Parse JSON in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897325/parse-json-in-jquery)

I can get this example to parse, but if I remove the beginning and ending square brackets it won't parse.  Can someone clarify why.  It appears that json doesn't need beginning and ending square brackets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this to help you visualize your JSON: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON data (which is an object) only contains one element: `mainunit`.

You don't need the `$.each`. Just do:

```
data.mainunit.sensors[0].tc; // 71.3
```

Your `$.each` will loop just once, and in that loop `learning` will be `data.mainunit`.

```
$.each(data, function(i, learning) {
    alert(i); // 'mainunit'
    alert(data.sensors[0].tc); // 71.3
});
```

EDIT: To loop through each sensor:

```
$.each(data.mainunit.sensors, function(i, sensor) {
    alert(sensor.tc);
});
```

Comment: I would use $.each to loop through each of the sensors right?

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects need starting and ending brackets, and what you have in your file is a JSON object (a key/pair value).

Comment: I thought his question was "but if I remove the beginning and ending square brackets it won't parse. Can someone clarify why."

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that he was accessing the object incorrectly, I didn't see that part.  BTW: JSON needs opening/closing brackets.

Comment: I beg to differ. `JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);`

Comment: `JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3])` = `'[1,2,3]'`.  As you can see it has `[` and `]` around it.  Those are opening/closing brackets.

Comment: Right. We have a different word for them in french, got me confused. You're right.

Comment: Ah, that make sense.  `[]` are square braces (brackets), and `{}` are curly braces (brackets).  JSON requires that the string start one or other.  Sorry for confusion. :-)